# asp.net: how to put an ampersand in the dropdownlist text?

Tags: asp.net

i want to put this text

```
&euro;
```

in the text of a dropdownlistitem, so at runtime it will show the euro sign

but .net nicely escapes my code, and then it becomes this:

```
&amp;euro;
```

and that will show in my dropdownlist, and that's not what i want.

Any other way to show € £  etc in a dropdownlist is accepted too.

code:

```
private void FillDropDownCurrency(DropDownList ddl)
        {
            ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem() { Value = CurrencyConstants.CHF_CURRENCY_CODE, Text = CurrencyConstants.CHF_CURRENCY_SYMBOL, Selected = false });
            ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem() { Value = CurrencyConstants.GBP_CURRENCY_CODE, Text = CurrencyConstants.GBP_CURRENCY_SYMBOL, Selected = false });
            ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem() { Value = CurrencyConstants.EURO_CURRENCY_CODE, Text = CurrencyConstants.EURO_CURRENCY_SYMBOL, Selected = true });
            ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem() { Value = CurrencyConstants.USD_CURRENCY_CODE, Text = CurrencyConstants.USD_CURRENCY_SYMBOL, Selected = false });

        }
```

The CurrencyConstants.EURO_CURRENCY_SYMBOL is the `&euro;` code

Comment: how are you wiring up your DropDownList?

Comment: Are you unable to put that euro character as a string you could try my approach... but I can't think of a reason why SLaks answer wouldn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use the actual `€` character.
You don't need to (and cannot) escape it yourself.

Comment: will that work for all special characters? Seems like he wants to cover many different currencies.

Comment: I've had strange things happen when trying to save files in visual studio with odd characters like this. Is there some setting in VS that would need to be changed?

Comment: @hunter: Make sure the file is encoded as UTF8.  (File, Advanced Save Options)

Comment: +1 Is there a scenario where this wouldn't work? I'm not sure what `CurrencyConstants` is but if it's coming from the database there might be some issue with storing that character? Not sure...

Comment: @hunter: That would be a database issue.  With proper encoding, Unicode characters will work everywhere  (set your DB fields to `nvarchar`).  Also, `CurrencyConstants` is probably a set of `const string` fields.

Comment: indeed, it's a set of const strings

Comment: OK, then making `CurrencyConstants.EURO_CURRENCY_SYMBOL = "€"` should work as well as for the other symbols

Comment: Nice, it works! One noticable thing however: so i've pasted the Euro and (british)Pound symbol in the text in the code behind, and when the page is rendered, the pound is escaped to `&pound;` and the Euro sign is just rendered as is. Doesn't prevent it from working though....

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to go with SLaks answer you could try binding this right on the page:

```
<select id="currencyDropDownList" name="currencyDropDownList">
    <option value="<%=CurrencyConstants.CHF_CURRENCY_CODE %>"><%= CurrencyConstants.CHF_CURRENCY_SYMBOL %></option>
    <option value="<%=CurrencyConstants.GBP_CURRENCY_CODE %>"><%= CurrencyConstants.GBP_CURRENCY_SYMBOL %></option>
    <option value="<%=CurrencyConstants.EURO_CURRENCY_CODE %>" selected="selected"><%= CurrencyConstants.EURO_CURRENCY_SYMBOL %></option>
    <option value="<%=CurrencyConstants.USD_CURRENCY_CODE %>"><%= CurrencyConstants.USD_CURRENCY_SYMBOL %></option>
</select>
```

Comment: just make sure you added the namespace of CurrencyConstraints to your web.config